# Controlling the width of content in a Flexbox HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a `flexbox` and in it, I have an image and text. For some reason, there is a big area of the `flexbox` where I can't place content in. It is like there is `padding` there and it won't let it go past it. I'm not too sure why the content can't go in this area.

The part highlighted in yellow is where I can't place anything. If it goes over this area, it will just go to the next line.
[image]

What I want it for it to stretch across because right now, the text looks too close together. how can I achieve this? [image]

```css
/*Header for picture, and description*/
#display {
    padding-top: 2em;
    border: solid .125em black;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: wrap;
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 0.9;
}

#display > * {
    flex: 1 1 5%;
    padding: 1em;
}

article{
    margin-right:20em;
}

article h1{
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;
}

article p{
    padding-top: 2em;
}
```

```html
   <section id="display">
        <figure id="headshot">
            <img src="images/GM05.png" alt="headshot"/>
        </figure>
        <article>
            <h1>Name Goes Here</h1>
            <p>Cras tristique gravida tellus, id fringilla lorem pellentesque iaculis. Donec vitae risus mauris. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nunc consectetur purus sed diam iaculis congue. Morbi vitae nisl est. Sed sed justo vitae risus porta commodo vestibulum eget est. Cras eu augue enim. Etiam at commodo tellus, at posuere ligula. Vivamus at dolor eget sem faucibus aliquet sed et diam. Mauris vel leo eget nulla pulvinar suscipit vitae eu sem. Quisque nisi nibh, aliquet sit amet urna non, commodo fringilla tellus. Nullam tincidunt est nec tellus laoreet, id mollis urna pulvinar. Donec ligula ipsum, ultrices in venenatis quis, ultricies ut enim. Vivamus porttitor lobortis dui, id aliquam ipsum imperdiet non.</p>
        </article>
    </section>
```

Removing the margin-right in the article tag fixes the issue, but now they aren't aligned correctly.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You must note that you have set a margin on the article.

The problem might be here:

```
article{
    margin-right:20em;
}
```

This pushes your `article` 20em's away from the right end of your `display`. Just remove the `margin` and run the code.

Comment: That fixes the issue, but then the text is out of place. See pic above

Comment: It's because you told css to treat article as 50% of the entire display with. The problem to your question is sorted  by the answer above. but making sure the text is nicely bundled as a paragraph is about the width size of the article. Try adding Padding on the article. e.g set box-sizing to padding-block; and add padding to squeeze the text in.

Comment: so like article{ box-sizing:padding-block; padding:2em;}